# does a husband pray for his seed (child until birth)?

Tags: tefilla, minhag, talmud-gemara, pregnancy-birth, tractate-brachot

in [Berakoth 60a](http://halakhah.com/berakoth/berakoth_60.html) it says

> Within the first three days a **man should pray** that the seed should not putrefy; from the third to the fortieth day he should pray that the child should be a male; from the fortieth day to three months he should pray that it should not be a sandal;  from three months to six months he should pray that it should not be still-born; from six months to nine months he should pray for a safe delivery.

do jew have a custom to pray this prayer? (is it printed? what groups of jews do it?),
or this is just theory?

Comment: wikipedia "SRY gene effects normally take place 6–8 weeks after foetus formation and inhibits the female anatomical structural growth in males. It also works towards developing the dominant male characteristics." 6 weeks = 42 days ~ 40 days

Comment: I can add a question, if the karyotype is XX, is it really good if the child has male characterisitcs. perhaps if XY, they pray for male characteristic.

Comment: @kouty probably it means a male לטובה (infertile is not a male)

Comment: I have heard that some people request a "Mi Sheberach l'cholim" for pregnant wives. Would this count as an answer to your question?

Comment: The example prayer is יהי רצון שתלד אשתי זכר. Should the other ones be the same? יהי רצון שלא תלד אשתי סנדל etc.

Comment: @DoubleAA on the forth day you can pray even if you do not know if there was conception?

Comment: @kouty see sifsai chachomim 10 here http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEQ5s.jpg

Comment: @hazoriz Shkoyech. I ask myself, if one made some genetical analysis of the foetus, in the 40 days if this will make the tefilot shav. bivchinat לא סמוי מן העין

Comment: @kouty MAYBE it is the idea is a human can not see it, it does not exist (bacteria are kosher to eat) so it is not teffilat shav until it is 40 days

Comment: @kouty maybe, the teffila is to have a zochor which can have children (not xx) and we can daven for the chromezomes to change. What we can't do is  that a "boy to be born" if inside is a girl but until 40 days she is halochakli not a girl

Comment: @hazoriz yes. interesting

Answer (score 4):

Such a tefillah for an easy labor is brought in [Seder Avodas Yisroel page 162](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42897&st=&pgnum=188), to be said after entering the 7th month of pregnancy.

> יהי רצון לפניך ה' אלהי ואלהי אבותי שתקל מעל אשתי פלונית בת פלונית את צער עיבורה ותוסיף ותתן לה כח כל ימי עיבורה שלא יותש כחה ולא כוח העובר על ידי דבר בעולם ותצילנה מפתקה של חוה ויהי בעת לדתה כי ימלאו ימיה ללדת לא יהפכו עליה ציריה ויצא הולד לאור העולם ברגע קטן ותלד כתרנגולת בקלות ובלי היזק לה ולא לולד ויהי שיולד בשעה טובה ובמזל טוב לחיים ולשלום ולבריאות לחן ולחסד ולעושר וכבוד ותמלא נא את משאלותי ומשאלות כל ישראל במידה טובה ישועה ורחמים  ואל תשיביני ריקם מלפניך; אמן.‏

Comment: Is this based on that Gemara? Where are the prayers for the other parts? Or is this just an innovation because obviously it's a good thing to pray for?

Comment: @DoubleAA I don't know - I just remembered seeing it in the siddur, came across this siddur and thought I would give it as an answer.

Comment: To be fair, this answer only addresses the fifth part of that sugya, and that's probably the only part of the sugya that's not a chiddush. No problem praying for an easy delivery (or a successful operation, or a lucrative business venture, or a smooth flight, or anything in the future). The chiddush lies in the other questions: that the semen should be viable, that the fetus should be a boy, that it should be well-formed and that it should be healthy - all of which relate to things that are happening *right now*, just not yet in the past.