# A Hebrew prayer upon discovering the news of having a baby?

Tags: tefilla, sources-mekorot, pregnancy-birth, baby-infant

I've found this [book](https://books.google.nl/books?id=T3L7aDAO6toC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) called: The Jewish Pregnancy book; 'A Resource for the Soul, Body & Mind during Pregnancy, Birth & the First Three Months', written by Sandy Falk, M.D., and Rabbi Daniel Judson with Steven A. Rapp.

Within this book there is this lovely prayer, and I wondered if there is a Hebrew version of this and wether it is usual to say such blessings.

The prayer upon discovering the news:
*We stand breathless before the Power of Creation that works through us to bring forth new life. We tremble with fear and joy.*

*Deep inside me a seed is growing. I am afraid, and I am filled with ecstasy.
May this promise of life come to be – our child.*

*We trust in the source of life, this power which grips us within and yet transcends us. Protect this fragile new beginning. May we find love and strength to nurture this gift of fertility and life. Sheltered under wings of love, may we grow to be partners with the source of life in the miracle of creation.*

Comment: From the way it's written, it sounds like this particular text was written in English rather than translated from Hebrew.  That's not to say you won't find a Hebrew text with the same gist.  (Also it sounds like it's meant for women specifically, so if Levi is your first name it might not be so appropriate...)

Comment: @Heshy It's seperated in a part for a woman and part as a couple

Comment: Rabbi Daniel Judson is a Reform rabbi, [who is married](http://www.nytimes.com/1999/05/09/style/sandy-falk-and-daniel-judson.html) to Dr. Sandy Falk.  He used to be the leader of [Temple Beth David](https://templebethdavid.com/) in Canton, MA, which is a Reform temple.

Comment: If you want to find out which tehillim could be said, ask your LOR.

Comment: Related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/77934/5120

Comment: With miscarriage rates and fetal mortality rates so high back then, as well as being in doubt for most of pregnancy if one is actually pregnant, people from hundreds of years ago wouldn't have ever had a Aha! moment about pregnancy with the confidence of a future person, at least not the same way most couples have now with a positive pregnancy test. And if this is a new phenomenon, it's unlikely there is classical liturgy for it.

Answer (score 1):

B’shaa tova !

There is a [Chabad custom](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1217817/jewish/Laws-of-Childbirth.htm) for the husband to say [Psalm 20](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.20?lang=bi) before going to bed and repeating the second verse.

Beyond this, there is a beautiful prayer found in the Yiddish Zultsbach prayer book from 1825

> May it be your will G-d, my L-rd and the L-rd of my ancestors, that
>   you will ease for me the difficulty of pregnancy, and that You will
>   increase my strength, and the strength of my fetus, so that my
>   strength and the strength of my fetus will not be weakened by any
>   weakness or loss of strength. And that you will save me from the slip
>   of Eve, who was punished, “I will increase your suffering and
>   distress, with suffering you will give birth to children.”
>
> When my
>   time to give birth will arrive, I will give birth easily, and without
>   any pain, and the baby will go out into the air of the world easily,
>   and without any harm to me or to the baby. And the baby will be born
>   with good luck [mazal tov], into life, peace, health, wealth, and
>   honor, and will find grace in Your eyes and in the eyes of all your
>   creations, and through this child will be fulfilled the verse: “There
>   will not be a mourner or a barren woman in your land, I will give you
>   a full life,” so you will complete my days and years, and my husband
>   and I will be able to raise this child to serve You and we will merit
>   to teach this child your holy Torah, and we will merit to have peace
>   and wealth, honor and rest.
>
> And guard us, my fetus and me, that we
>   will not be harmed, not physically, and not in any of our limbs, and
>   not in any of our nerves, and not in our skin and not in our flesh,
>   and not on the inside of our bodies or on the outside. And you will
>   strengthen my courage, my strength, and my might, as it says: “There
>   will be healing for your flesh, and refreshment for your bones.

For the continuation and husband's version see [here](http://jewishmom.com/pregnancy-inspiration/inspiration-for-pregnancy/tchinot/).